# c# navigation between forms

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I am confused about how to navigate between Forms in c#

I want to do the following:

1. from `Form1` opening the `Form2` and make `Form2` on the top of the original one `Form1` and then get back to `Form1` and user are not allowed to use `Form1` untill they close the child `Form2` to get back to `Form1`
2. with the same scenario but I may pass parameter from `Form2` to `Form1`

I searched but think are not clear in my mind I found that there is something called MDI Parent And Child like the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076526/mdi-form-in-c-sharp-parent-and-child) but

I do not want the child from to be inside the original one

I do not the original from style to be change and be in that gray one

that way I think what I need to use is **NOT** MDI Parent And Child

please help I appreciate long explanation description with example

Comment: What you want to do is open your Form2 as a `Modal` to form1. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503079/how-do-i-make-a-form-modal-in-windows-forms

Comment: For the second scenario, there are many ways you can pass back the data from form2 to form1. One of them is using property accessors on the form2 object. Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587952/passing-data-between-forms

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show a form from another form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618830/show-a-form-from-another-form)

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that the data you are interested in on `Form2` can be accessed by read/write properties.  In my example, I show that as a simple string property called `UsefulData`.  Here's the normal way to do what you are asking:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      var dialog = new Form2();                       //create an instance of Form2
      dialog.UsefulData = "Some Useful Data";         //set one or more properties of that form
      string result = "No Result Yet";                //a place to store the eventual data from Form2
      if (dialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK) //passing "this" properly parents the dialog to your Form1
      {                                               //note that I only get the data if the user pressed OK
          result = dialog.UsefulData;                 //get the data
      }
      //do something with that result
  }
```

There you go!